# XAML: Property inheritance WITHOUT WPF?

Tags: c#, xaml, dependency-properties

I'm working on a XAML - based CUI (console user interface) framework (which should look like Turbo Vision) for C# and I need to use property inheritance with dependency properties.

Is there ANY way to accomplish that?

I would prefer to be able to derive future widgets from `DependencyObject`, not "Visual" or something similar, because I want to have my own system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This discussion I had with myself over on the MSDN forums may be useful to you:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpf/thread/6E73F05F-0141-46F1-BB06-EA7ADF30B267

That was a year ago. I don't remember ever completing that project.. =P